# Previewing multiple uploaded images individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three image upload fields in my form. I am trying to preview the images before uploading. Till now i have been able to preview only one at a time. but i am trying to preview all of them simultaneously. Like

I am currently previewing like this.

```js
function previewImages() {

var $preview = $('#preview').empty();

if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

function readAndPreview(i, file) {

if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
  return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
} // else...

var reader = new FileReader();

$(reader).on("load", function() {
  $preview.append($("<img/>", {src:this.result, height:500}));
});

reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}

}

$('#file-input').on("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Image 2</label>
    <input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
</div>
<img id='img-upload'/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Image 3</label>
<input id="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in your code.

1. **Never** use duplicate id's . That's the main reason your code works only for the first input type file. You use `id='file-input'` on all inputs. That's not correct HTML wise. Use classes instead or other html attributes.
2. You select the preview container but only the first one. `$preview = $('#preview').empty();` where by writing `$('#preview')`, jquery finds the first item with id preview, selects it, empties it and then ignores all other divs with the same id. This is firstly because you don't select the corresponding `preview` div to the changed input file ( no connection between them in your `var` declaration ) and because again you use duplicate ( multiple ) id's in your HTML structure. Which will generate a lot of ' strange ' errors.

But even if you would use classes instead of id's ( `class='preview'` ) it won't exactly work because it will just select the first div with class preview and append all previews to that div.

So to make a connection between input and it's preview, use something like `var $preview = $(this).next('.preview').empty();` . This way you know jQuery will select the  next sibling  with class preview of the changed input.

Alternatively ( if your HTML structure should change and preview is not exactly after the input ) you should use `$(this).siblings('.preview').empty()`

The most important thing you should learn from this answer is NOT to use same id`s on the page. And when you have multiple items with corresponding elements, select them accordingly.

```js
function previewImages() {
  const $preview = $(this).next('.preview').empty();

  if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

  function readAndPreview(i, file) {

    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
      return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...

    const reader = new FileReader();

    $(reader).on("load", function() {
      $preview.append($("<img/>", {
        src: this.result,
        height: 100
      }));
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }

}

$('.file-input').on("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Image 1</label>
  <input class="file-input" type="file" multiple>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
<img class='img-upload' />
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Image 2</label>
  <input class="file-input" type="file" multiple>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
<img class='img-upload' />
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Image 3</label>
  <input class="file-input" type="file" multiple>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

*SIDE NOTE* . You should use `const` and/or `let` instead of `var` when declaring variables.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $preview=null;
function previewImages() {
 $preview = $(this).next('#preview').empty();
if (this.files) 
$.each(this.files,function(index,file){
   readAndPreview(index,file);
});
}
function readAndPreview(i, file) {
if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
  return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
} // else...
var reader = new FileReader();
$(reader).on("load", function() {
  $preview.append($("<img/>", {src:this.result, height:100}));
});
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

$('.file-input').on("change", previewImages);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Image 2</label>
    <input class="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
</div>
<img id='img-upload'/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Image 3</label>
<input class="file-input" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Try this. css ids are unique for a page. if you want to access multiple elements with same selector use class.

Comment: as you see. when you upload the second image, it will be appended to the same div as the first one. Plus there are more duplicate id-s. And they are not `css ids`

Comment: Generally we can say don't use duplicate ids but it is possible to use.@MihaiT see my code.

Comment: Sometimes it might work sometimes not. That means it's not good practice and should not be used. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute . See here and other questions on SO or on google. Plus, you say `css ids`  but they are not `css ids`. And plus `copy/paste` my answer and overwrite your own, it's also no good practice. ( see `height:100` for example )